# How to keep the selected menu active using jquery, when the user comes back to page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a typical menu structure -

```
<Ul class="nav">
<li>Menu1</li>
<li>menu2</li>
-------
</ul>
```

When I click on certain menu, as per my jquery written on load of layout.html, it selects particular menu.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
      jQuery('.nav>li>a').each(function(){
        if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
  </script>
```

But on that page if I click on certain link which takes me on some other page and then when I come back the menu item does not remain selected.

How can I modify my jquery to achieve this?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

As SJ-B is saying, HTML5 Web Storage is a good solution.

If you don't intend to click more than one or two pages away from the page with your list menu, you could add a query to the link that takes you away form the page e.g. the id of one of your list menus.

`href="somepage.html` could become something like this `href="somepage.html?menu_id=menu5`

When using `window.history.back()`, you could then fish the `id` out of the URL using `window.location.search` and use `id` to select the list menu.

Comment: Can you pl elaborate little more?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Session Object of HTML5.

```
sessionStorage.varName = id of selected item.
```

on load just check if the sessionStorage.varName has value or undefined, if not then get the value

```
`var value = sessionStorage.varName;` and set it.
```

Comment: I just know some methods about Session Object(below) - Can it be set using jquery?   sessionStorage.setItem("test", "yo");
sessionStorage.getItem("test"); // yo

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple css code. Use active attribute like

```
a:active
{
 //Some style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to achieve this.

```
var lastele=siteurl.substring(siteurl.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    jQuery(".nav>li> a").each(function(){
    var anchorhref=jQuery(this).attr("href");
    var finalhref=anchorhref.substring(anchorhref.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    if(finalhref==lastele){
        jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li id="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript :

```
// http://mywebsite.com#home
// location.hash === '#home'
jQuery('.nav ' + location.hash).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there could be many ways, on which is this which i like and always use:
`It works when you path name is same as your link name` For e.g. *yourwebsite.com/Menu1*

```
function setNavigation() {
    var n = window.location.pathname,t;
    n = n.replace("/", "");
    t = $("ul li:contains(" + n + ")");
    t.addClass("active");
}
```

You can than define styling in your `active` class as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this when googling for something similar. I have a JQueryUI accordion menu. My menu is in an included script (classic asp), so it is on every page but I think it is a similar situation. I cobbled something together based on SJ-B's answer (don't know why it was down voted).

I have this:

```
function saveSession(id) {
    if (window.sessionStorage) {
        sessionStorage.activeMenu = $("#jqmenu").accordion("option", "active") ;
        sessionStorage.activeLink = id ;
    }
}
```

and this

```
$(function() {
  //give every li in the menu a unique id
  $('#jqmenu a').attr('id', function(i) {
        return 'link'+(i+1);
  });
  var activeMenu = 0;
  var activeLink = "";
  if (window.sessionStorage) {
    activeMenu = parseInt(sessionStorage.activeMenu);
    activeLink = sessionStorage.activeLink;
  }
  $("#" + activeLink).parent().addClass("selectedmenu");
  $("#jqmenu").accordion({collapsible: true, active: activeMenu, heightStyle: "content", header: "h3"});
  $("#jqmenu a").click(function() { saveSession($(this).attr('id')); });
});
```

OK, a bit untidy and cobbled together from various suggestions (I'm still learning), but it seems to work. Tried on IE11 and Firefox. Chrome can't find localhost but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

add lines below

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       $("a[href='"+window.location+"']").addClass("selected");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location.pathname,
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$"); 
$('.nav li').each(function () {
    if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```